# C++ lockless queue crashes with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-fences

I'm trying to gain better understanding of controlling memory order when coding for multiple threads. I've used mutexes a lot in the past to serialize variable access, but I'm trying to avoid those where possible to improve performance.

I have a queue of pointers that may be filled by many threads and consumed by many threads. It works fine with a single thread, but crashes when I run with multiple threads. It looks like the consumers may be getting duplicates of the pointers which causes them to be freed twice. It's a little hard to tell since when I put in any print statements, it runs fine without crashing.

To start with I'm using a pre-allocated vector to hold the pointers. I keep 3 atomic index variables to keep track of what elements in the vector need processing. It may be worth noting that I tried using a _queue type where the elements themselves were atomic by that did not seem to help. Here is the simpler version:

```
std::atomic<uint32_t> iread;
std::atomic<uint32_t> iwrite;
std::atomic<uint32_t> iend;
std::vector<JEvent*> _queue;

// Write to _queue (may be thread 1,2,3,...)
while(!_done){
    uint32_t idx = iwrite.load();
    uint32_t inext = (idx+1)%_queue.size();
    if( inext == iread.load() ) return kQUEUE_FULL;
    if( iwrite.compare_exchange_weak(idx, inext) ){
        _queue[idx] = jevent; // jevent is JEvent* passed into this method
        while( !_done ){
            if( iend.compare_exchange_weak(idx, inext) ) break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

and from the same class

```
// Read from _queue (may be thread 1,2,3,...)
while(!_done){
    uint32_t idx = iread.load();
    if(idx == iend.load()) return NULL;
    JEvent *Event = _queue[idx];
    uint32_t inext = (idx+1)%_queue.size();
    if( iread.compare_exchange_weak(idx, inext) ){
        _nevents_processed++;
        return Event;
    }
}
```

I should emphasize that I am really interested in understanding why this doesn't work. Implementing some other pre-made package would get me past this problem, but would not help me avoid making the same type of mistakes again later.

**UPDATE**
I'm marking Alexandr Konovalov's answer as correct (see my comment in his answer below). In case anyone comes across this page, the corrected code for the "Write" section is:

```
std::atomic<uint32_t> iread;
std::atomic<uint32_t> iwrite;
std::atomic<uint32_t> iend;
std::vector<JEvent*> _queue;

// Write to _queue (may be thread 1,2,3,...)
while(!_done){
    uint32_t idx = iwrite.load();
    uint32_t inext = (idx+1)%_queue.size();
    if( inext == iread.load() ) return kQUEUE_FULL;
    if( iwrite.compare_exchange_weak(idx, inext) ){
        _queue[idx] = jevent; // jevent is JEvent* passed into this method
        uint32_t save_idx = idx;
        while( !_done ){
            if( iend.compare_exchange_weak(idx, inext) ) break;
            idx = save_idx;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ABA problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem

Comment: Are you sure that you've got enough contention to make it worthwhile to have a lockless queue?

Comment: It might be worth reading how others have solved the *multi producer multi consumer queue* (mpmc) problem as this might give you some insight into what you're missing. From what I recall of the problem, it requires more sophistication in your checks than you've currently got.

Comment: @UKMonkey Yes. I can make it work with locks and it slows it down from ~4MHz to ~35kHz.

Comment: @Slava. It's possible since the queue is used as a ringer buffer so the indexes do roll back around to the same values. The crash seems to occur very quickly regardless of how many threads I use (as long as it is more than 1). Seems a little unlikely given some of the numbers (queue size vs. threads), but worth checking. I will do some tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, one possible issue can occurs when there are 2 writers and 1 reader. Suppose that 1st writer stops just before

```
 _queue[0] = jevent;
```

and 2nd writer signals via iend that its _queue[1] is ready to be read. Then, reader via iend sees that _queue[0] is ready to be read, so we have data race.

I recommend you try Relacy Race Detector, that ideally applies to such kind of analysis.

Comment: Alexandr: Thanks for your suggestion. The purpose of the inner while loop in the writer section is to prevent that exact scenario(though I could be missing something). In the scenario you describe, the second writer thread should get stuck in that inner while loop until iend is set equal to "1". This won't happen until the first writer thread goes through that same inner while loop and changes iend from "0" to "1". And that doesn't happen until it has written to it's slot in _queue.

Comment: Well, no. 1st run of  iend.compare_exchange_weak() in 2nd writer thread definitely returns fail, but 2nd run succeeded (so the thread leaves the inner loop), because after 1st run idx was updated to current iend.

Comment: Alexandr: I had to stare at your comment and my code for a while before finally realizing that I had not fully understood compare_exchange_weak. I had not appreciated that if the call "fails" then it updates the expected value ("idx" in my case). This is precisely why I came to SO. It's an embarrassing mistake on my part, but I'm glad to understand it now. Thanks!